# Docker Containers Not Consistently Joining Specified Networks Despite Correct Compose Files

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-network

I'm facing an issue with Docker networking. I have 10 microservices, each defined in its own Docker Compose file. All of them are supposed to connect to three external networks: frontend, backend, and mongodb.

Here's a snippet of my Docker Compose network configuration for each service:

```
networks:
    frontend:
        external: true
    backend:
        external: true
    mongodb:
        external: true
```

The issue is that after building and running the containers, they don't consistently join all three networks. Some join only frontend and backend, some join only mongodb and frontend, and some join all three as expected.

Things I've already checked:

- No service dependencies that could affect network joining.
- All external networks are pre-created.
- Sufficient system resources are available.
- Syntax and indentation in the Docker Compose files are correct.

Manually joining the missing networks using docker network connect works perfectly, but I'd like to understand why it's not happening automatically.

Has anyone faced a similar issue or have any insights on what could be going wrong?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Why do you have so many networks?  Can you delete all of the `networks:` blocks and use the `default` network that Compose provides for you?  Do you have a [mcve], also showing the container setup, and demonstrating why you think the networks aren't being joined?